# Modify SharePoint list hyperlinks in excel

Tags: 2013, excel, hyperlink, sync

I have a list in SharePoint 2013 which contains old hyperlinks which I want to change. I want to do it in excel 2013 but I cannot find a way to update the already modified hyperlinks in excel to the list.

My goal is to edit the hyperlinks in excel and to somehow apply those changes to the SharePoint list. I do not want to do it in access as I have to write a query to modify the links but in excel this can be done with a formula.

Comment: Excel can only Read SharePoint ListData, Excel can not write back to SharePoint (but MS-Access can) So if you know how to write an Access SQL-Query then MS-Access is the way to go. Altnernative methods are Powershell or JavaScript(JSOM) code

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it in Excel 2013?? Thats bit confusing. If you are looking to edit in Datasheet view. Please select Datasheet View from the ribbon and the items will be displayed in Excel format which i guess you can copy paste in an excel document.